# Configuring gitlab hook plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gitlab, webhooks, gitlab-7

we've created a continuous integration workflow with Gitlab (v7.9.2) and Jenkins(v1.596.2). We defined a Jenkins job to build every push that is made to every repository on Gitlab with the Gitlab hook:

```
 http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/gitlab/build_now
```

It's bad practice to let one job build all the tasks so we want to use the [Gitlab-Web-hook plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-hook-plugin) to define a template job witch creates a new job for every unknown repository that triggers the Web Hook, like described in the Gitlab-Web-hook plugin description under section Templates for unknown repositories.

> The plugin can be configured to automatically create projects when the hook is activated by a GitLab repo unknown to Jenkins.

Now we have difficulties finding the right configuration, or even how to start integrating this plugin into the workflow. We spend a day searching for tutorials of default configurations on this subject and couldnt find any.

We hope the community can help us with this or set us off with some usefull hints, trics or tutorials. It's the last piece of the puzzle for us.

Thank you